# Trying to add if statement values to the total answer in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

quite new to Java so trying to understand it can be difficult.

Anyways the problem, as part of a task I have to code a theatre tickets console application. I've almost finished I'm just trying to add the last part

As part of the task we have to ask the user if they want the tickets to be posted, if yes this incurs a charge which will be applied to the total charge. Currently I'm unsure of how to do this. At the moment I am currently working with If and else statements and.. Well you'll see below.

```
   System.out.println ("Do you require the tickets to be posted?\n(£2.34 for post and packing for the entire order)\n(please enter 'Yes' on the next line if you require postage)");
   String postinp = scanner.next();

           if ("Yes".equals(postinp)){
            System.out.println("Postage will be added to your cost" );
           }
            else
            System.out.println("Postage will not be added to your cost");
```

Well I'm trying to code, if the user enters 'yes' then it adds on the postage charge to the total, but in this section of code I'm unsure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me where you initialize your scanner?

Comment: Well you need to make a variable for the charges and sum them up. Do you have the charges as a number or are you only working with Strings?

Comment: its okay, except for the "Ye" .. It should be "Yes"

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `if-statement` all we need to do is add your £2.34 to the total sum being calculated by the program.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       double total = 10.00;
       System.out.println("Do you require the tickets to be posted?\n(£2.34 for post and packing for the entire order)\n(please enter 'Yes' on the next line if you require postage)");

       if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input.next())) {
          System.out.println("Postage will be added to your cost");
          total = total + 2.34;
       } else
          System.out.println("Postage will not be added to your cost");
   }
```

Comment: Well what is your total cost? You haven't provided it to us with the code above. Just simply replace your total cost with `total` in my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, just changed the code and it worked. May I ask why a double wouldn't work here?

Comment: @TomCummins A double does work here, since you've provided that 2.34 is added to our total we can't use an `int`. A `float` would also be applicable. My guess is that you need to change the type of the variable holding the total.

Comment: Right thanks for your help, I was trying to sort this out for the last hour. I was using:  
double post0 = total + 2.34;
and that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

use scanner.nextLine() insead of scanner.next();

and use "Yes" instead of "Ye"

Comment: It shouldn't matter if all we're expecting is one word

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is change

```
if ("Ye".equals(postinp)) {
```

to

```
if ("yes".equals(postinp.toLowerCase())) {
```

That way it won't be case sensitive to what the user inputs, because otherwise they'd have to input `Yes` exactly.

Comment: or you can just use `.equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

You can add more code within the `then-else` blocks of an `if` statement

```
if ( "Yes".equals(postinp) ) 
{
    this.cost += 2.34 ; // or whatever it is you need to do

    System.out.println("Postage will be added to your cost" );
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("Postage will not be added to your cost");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to resolve two things--evaluating the answer and then acting accordingly.

Try this:

```
String postinp = scanner.next();
if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(postinp)) {
   cost += postage;
   System.out.println("Postage will be added to your cost" );
}
else {
   System.out.println("Postage will not be added to your cost");
}
```

The `if` block checks if the result is some form of "yes" without regard to case. Then it assumes that `cost` and `postage` variables (`float`s) are available and initialized from somewhere. In the "yes" case, `cost` is augmented by `postage`.

Also, since you are just learning it isn't a big deal, but at some point you might want to consider your postage to be a value consumed from a constant or from a configuration file. Maybe the initial cost can be too.